# How to Unite Same PostgreSQL Data

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I have a postgresql statement which is:

```
( select cast(start_time as date) as time , SUM(count) as  count 
from tbl_product  
where ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-08-30 23:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-01 20:00:00' ) 
and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 23  and extract(hour from start_time) <= 24)      
group by time order by time limit 5 )  

UNION ( select cast(start_time as date) as time , SUM(count) as  count 
from tbl_product  
where ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-08-31 23:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-01 20:00:00' ) 
and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 0  and extract(hour from start_time) < 20)      
group by time order by time limit 5 )
```

But it returns the same data for the same date, because of a `UNION` statement

```
time            count
date            numeric
"2016-08-31"    543595
"2016-08-31"    3666277
"2016-09-01"    3365093
```

How can I add these data values like:

```
time            count
date            numeric
"2016-08-31"    4209872
"2016-09-01"    3365093
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `GROUP BY` out of the individual queries. Something like that:

```
SELECT time, SUM(count) as  count FROM (
    ( select cast(start_time as date) as time , count 
    from tbl_product  
    where ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-08-30 23:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-01 20:00:00' ) 
    and (extract(hour from start_time) >= 23))  
        UNION ALL
    ( select cast(start_time as date) as time , count 
    from tbl_product  
    where ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-08-31 23:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-01 20:00:00' ) 
    and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 0  and extract(hour from start_time) < 20))
    ) AS t
GROUP BY time ORDER by time;
```

I've also changed the `UNION` to a `UNION ALL`, because it seems to make more sense in this case. Finally, the test `extract(hour from start_time) <= 24` is always true, so it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
select
exe.time_,
sum(exe.count_)
from
(
    select cast(start_time as date) as time_ , SUM(count) as  count_ 
    from tbl_product  
    where ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-08-30 23:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-01 20:00:00' ) 
    and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 23  and extract(hour from start_time) <= 24)      
    group by time order by time limit 5   
    UNION 
    select cast(start_time as date) as time_, SUM(count) as  count_
    from tbl_product  
    where ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-08-31 23:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-01 20:00:00' ) 
    and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 0  and extract(hour from start_time) < 20)      
    group by time order by time limit 5 
) exe
group by exe.time_
```